# cassandra 2.0.11 - column count for partition key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Lets consider following table taken from http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

```
CREATE TABLE temperature 
(
    weatherstation_id text,
    event_time timestamp,
    temperature text,
    PRIMARY KEY (weatherstation_id,event_time)
);
```

So `weatherstation_id` is the partition key and `event_time` is the clustering column. 
Data is loaded to that table and then we run query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM temperature WHERE weatherstation_id = '1234ABCD'
```

So actually we are asking for number of columns in underlying cassandra storage row.

**1) Is it a O(1) operation? 
 
2) If not - how to achievie O(1) in counting columns in a cassandra storage row? Use counters?**

(I am using Cassandra v2.0.11)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an O(1) operation, because it must scan the partition and count the number of columns. If you want a constant time count, you'll have to keep track of it some other way. You can use counter columns, but you should read [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters) first.

Comment: I am quite surprised that column count within partition is not stored in partition meta-data or something like that

Comment: @fuggy_yama Storing the column count doesn't help. Data for a partition could potentially be spread across multiple SSTables and Memtables and the counts would need to be combined. Unfortunately, you can't just add these counts together since the same columns may exist in more than one location.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a roll-up approach for a problem like this.  You store your events in a table, then periodically you run a task to aggregate whatever stats you need about the data, and then insert it into another table.  The second table acts like a cache so that if you are running a webserver for example, it can serve those stats immediately.  If you use a partition key that gets you directly to the row with the stat you want, then it would be O(1) access time.  The drawback is the roll-up table would not have the exact count at any given moment, but with distributed computing, being close to the right answer is usually good enough.

Comment: sounds ok (in my case 100% precise counts are not necessary) but it requires running a scheduled hadoop job to count that statistics - are hadoop jobs excpensive?

Comment: Hadoop jobs can be expensive if the tables being processed are large.  If you are doing roll ups, you'd want to avoid re-scanning the same data on each update.  There are other approaches besides Hadoop, such as spark.

Comment: Specifically, you should look at Spark Streaming, which will allow you to keep the counts updated within a specified time window.